# Multiple Hosted Service With Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, simple-injector, ihostedservice

i'm trying to follow this example [here](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/generichostintegration.html)

the only thing is i need to inject multiple hosted services instead of one like this

```
services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
{
    // Registers the hosted service as singleton in Simple Injector
    // and hooks it onto the .NET Core Generic Host pipeline.
    options.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService<IProcessor>>();
    options.AddHostedService<MyHostedService<IProcessor>>();
});
```

the implementation of AddHostedService register one instance as singleton of IHostedService Interface
I tried registering multiple implementations of IHostedService with services.TryAddEnumerable with no success any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the code above doesn't work for you?

Comment: the ExecuteAsync method doesn't execute for the second registration

Comment: I'll try to add a code source to GitHub for a complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue. I used the following code in a Visual Studio 2022 ASP.NET Core MVC 6 project:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using SimpleInjector;

var container = new Container();

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;

services.AddControllersWithViews();

services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options =>
{
    options.AddHostedService<MyHostedService1>();
    options.AddHostedService<MyHostedService2>();
});

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.Services.UseSimpleInjector(container);

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

`MyHostedService1` and `MyHostedService2` are defined as follows:

```cs
class MyHostedService1 : IHostedService
{
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting {this.GetType().Name}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}

class MyHostedService2 : IHostedService
{
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting {this.GetType().Name}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The Console output from the web application is the following:

```
Starting MyHostedService1
Starting MyHostedService2
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5071
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: f:\VS2022\HodgePodge\AspNetCore6MVC\
```

From this I conclude that both hosted services are started, which means the problem you have is not reproducible with the code you posted.

Comment: my mistake thanks steven I was blocking the context a silly mistake